# Android Splashscreen or loading screen on 3.1

Tags: android, android-3.1-honeycomb

I made a splash screen from a tutorial and it works great on Android 2.3+ and even on Android 4.0+ BUT if i ran it on my Galaxy Tab (**Android 3.1**) it is **starting TWICE the application.** 
Really annoying what can i do to solve this on 3.1 ?

Here is the code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity 
{

protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 2000; // time to display the splash screen in ms

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    try{

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    overridePendingTransition(0 , 0);

    // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
               // finish();

                try{
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(SplashScreen.this, MySecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    ki(e);
                }

            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ki(ex);
    }

 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}   



 //Toaster
    public void ki(Exception message)
    {
    Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message.toString(), 1);
    myToast.show();
}



}
```

So as you see it is a simple threading activity change, but when it changes, it is starts the MySecondActivity twice.

What the heck?

E D I T:

I just realized, this bug only happens if i **start the app on landscape mode** while it is on splashing/loading screen. Maybe it is a valuable info to solve this..

Comment: [Splash screens are evil, don’t use them!](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=632)

Comment: :| It is a nice article, but i MUST use them. Job duty.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use sleep. Maybe you could try this instead.

```
private void popSplash() {
    Message msg = splashHandler.obtainMessage();
    splashHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 2000);
}

private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MySecondActivity.class);;
        finish();
    }
};
```

just call the popSplash in onCreate.

---

This worked for me -

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            // For tablets, to avoid dublicate onCreates.
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it works just like my solution but not solves the twice Activity start. But i will use this.. it is just a few lines, nice snippet.

Comment: I had this problems myself. I updated my code with a snippet that worked for me

Comment: Not solved, but i just realized this bug also happens on mobiles with android 2.3 if i start on landscape mode. In portrait everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 5000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if(_active) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MyApp.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            _active = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```